# Keyboard randomly stops working

Tags: keyboard, 18.10

I have this weird bug where the keyboard suddenly wont respond for abut 45 seconds, and then come back to normal. It usually happens when i open a web browser.

The weirdest part is that keyboard shortcuts (such as `Alt + Tab`) dont stop working at all, while text input keys just wont do anything

Its something minor, but its still very irritating.
Any ideas of what it might be?

Comment: It's also possible that you're using a very underpowered computer that struggles while loading heavy software.

Comment: Your computer may be under very heavy stress. Please open a terminal and leave it open. When this problem occurs, as soon as your keyboard is "back", switch to terminal and enter the command `w`. Paste here only the first line of its output.

Comment: As pointed out by GabrielaGarcia and FedonKadifeli, im probably running short on processment power. My computer is indeed not that strong, and it happens only when i do a heavy-ish task, such as open a browser. Thanks!

Comment: However this may be due to a badly behaving or runaway process. You have to find the culprit and eliminate it. `top` and other similar commands in this family will show you that.